# Sufficient conditions for $\pi_1(X\vee Y)=\pi_1(X)\ast\pi_1(Y)$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

What are sufficient conditions such that $\pi_1(X\vee Y)=\pi_1(X)\ast\pi_1(Y)$ for spaces $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: see  the answer of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320812/fundamental-group-of-the-wedge-sum-of-two-spaces

Answer (score 1):

For example if the pasting point has a contractible neighborhood in both spaces.

Comment: how about a proof?

Comment: It's almost trivial if you know Van Kampen's theorem: just define $U_1:=X \cup V_1$ and $U_2:=Y \cup V_2$ where $V_1,V_2$ are the contractible neighborhood of the pasting point respectively in $Y$ and in $X$.